# Request user recenttracks from lastfm with codeigniter and xmlrpc

Tags: php, codeigniter, xml-rpc, last.fm

I'm trying to get some information from last.fm with Codeigniter.

```
$this->load->library("xmlrpc");
$this->xmlrpc->server("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/", 80);
$this->xmlrpc->method("user.getrecenttracks");
$request = array("rj", "b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026");
$this->xmlrpc->request($request);
if(!$this->xmlrpc->send_request())
{
    echo $this->xmlrpc->display_error();
}
```

The only response I always get is: *Invalid parameters - Your request is missing a required parameter*

It tried some variations with the request array, but it simply doesn't work the way I handle it...

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/99116/ looks like you might need to also include your API key in the request

Comment: Yes. I do that in my script. But I didn't want to post it here ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. `$request` should actually be written like this:

```
$request = array(
                 array(
                       array(
                             'user'=>'rj', 
                             'api_key'=>'b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026'
                            ),
                       'struct'
                      )
                );
```

The actual request that CodeIgniter's XML-RPC class constructs will then look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>user.getrecenttracks</methodName>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value>
                <struct>
                    <member>
                        <name>user</name>
                        <value>
                            <string>rj</string>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                    <member>
                        <name>api_key</name>
                        <value>
                            <string>b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026</string>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                </struct>
            </value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodCall>
```

You can see an example Last.fm XML-RPC request [here](http://www.last.fm/api/xmlrpc). Note that you should "send your params as named arguments using a struct in the first param node." Keeping that in mind, the [CodeIgniter docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/xmlrpc.html) state:

> If you use data types other than
>   strings, or if you have several
>   different data types, you will place
>   each parameter into its own array,
>   with the data type in the second
>   position.

Hope that helps.